# React Highmap this.normalizeTimeTickInterval is not a function

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I'm trying to build a highmap using highcharts react

and here's my configurations and live example, but i'm getting the following exception all the time  `this.normalizeTimeTickInterval is not a function`, it's due to the time series but i'm not sure what is the issue exactly,

here's a live example: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ua6ysn?file=Hello.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - I encourage to use official Highcharts react wrapper which is fully supported by Highcharts support team.

Docs: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react

Second - Notice that heatmap chart type requires heatmap module, not Highmaps. How to import modules you can find in the above documentation.

Here is a working demo with your config in our official Wrapper:
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-kw2gg

Comment: Thanks, my bad i was confused by the different libraries